# Triangle with each Angle is zero

Tags: geometry, triangles, hyperbolic-geometry

It is known that in Hyperbolic Geometry angle sum of a triangle is strictly less than $\pi.$

> Can we find a hyperbolic triangle with each angle is zero?
>
> If it is so, is there any characterization of such triangles?
>
> If not, is there any geometry in which "triangle with each angle is zero" exists?

Comment: yes, they are sometimes called ideal triangles

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_triangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Will Jagy pointed out, the answer is yes and these are called *ideal triangles*. Perhaps the simplest explicit example is given by the set

$$T = \{(x,y) \colon |x|<1, \ y>\sqrt{1-x^2} \}$$

using the upper-half model of the hyperbolic plane. This is the triangle pictured on the left in [Wikipedia illustration](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:IdealTriangle_HalfPlane.jpg):

[image]